# angular-cli: how to add external libraries (jquery, bootstrap)

Tags: angular, npm, angular-cli

Currently I have to do:

- install local libs `npm install bootstrap` and `npm install jquery`
- create a folder `src\assets`
- copy all files in node_modules\bootstrap and node_modules\jquery

In index.html

```
<script src="assets/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="assets/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Any better way?

Comment: It literally says in the documentation how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read this and you will understand:

https://github.com/angular/angular-cli#3rd-party-library-installation

Basically you just have to add it to the `scripts` property in the `angular-cli.json` file (`apps[0]`).

```
"scripts": [
  "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
  "../node_modules/tether/dist/js/tether.js",
  "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"
]
```